# Autocorrelation functions - haven ratio

Tags: integration, correlation-functions, diffusion, molecular-dynamics

I'm studying Haven coefficients (I created [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/780353/mean-squared-displacement-cross-and-no-cross) but with MSD). Right now I have question referring to calculating haven ratio using velocity-velocity autocorrelation functions. What I have found in articles is that tracer diffusion (which is the nominator of haven ratio) is described by this equation:

$D^*=\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left \langle \overline{v(0)}\cdot \overline{v(t)} \right \rangle dt$

And d.c. ionic conductivity (which is the denominator of haven ratio) is described by this equation:

$D_\sigma=\frac{1}{3N}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{i,j}^{1...N}\left \langle \overline{v_i(0)}\cdot \overline{v_j(t)} \right \rangle dt$

Where N is the number of (mobile) ions, $v_j(t)$ is vectorial velocity of ion number j at time t

I made code in Python calculating this coefficients, but I'm getting very weird results: negatives ones and larger than 1 (which could not be).

This is the code for calculating velocity autocorrelation function for tracer diffusion:

```
def calculate_autocorrelation(velocities, N, k):
    cv = np.zeros(shape=(k))

    # cv = np.array([velocities[0][0]*velocities[0][0]+velocities[0][0]*velocities[0][1]+...])

    # for every time step
    for step in range(0, k-1):
        cv_sum = 0
        # for every atom
        for c in range(0, N):
            cv_sum+=np.dot(velocities[step][c], velocities[0][c])
        cv[step] = cv_sum/N

    return cv
```

And this is the code for calculating velocity autocorrelation function for d.c. ionic conductivity:

```
def calculate_cross_autocorrelation(velocities, N, k):
    cv = np.zeros(shape=(k))

    # for every time step
    for step in range(0, k-1):
        cv_sum = 0
        # for every atom
        for c in range(0, N):
            for cc in range(0, N):
                cv_sum+=np.dot(velocities[step][c], velocities[0][cc])
        cv[step] = cv_sum/N

    return cv
```

After calculating these autocorrelation arrays I normalize them and integrate to obtain these coefficients (nominator and denominator):

```
autoCR = calculate_autocorrelation(oxygen_velocities, N_oxygen_orig, oxygen_steps_orig)
autoCR = autoCR/np.max(autoCR)

autoCrossCR = calculate_cross_autocorrelation(oxygen_velocities, N_oxygen_orig, oxygen_steps_orig)
autoCrossCR = autoCrossCR/np.max(autoCrossCR)

D_tracer = 1/3*integrate.simps(autoCR*10**(-20), dx=dt, even='avg')
D_tracer = 1/(3*N)*integrate.simps(autoCrossCR*10**(-20), dx=dt, even='avg')
```

I multiply it by this $10^{-20}$, because of the units in the simulation (coordinates are expressed in angstroms).

Also the data I have is in shape (k, N, 3), where k is time steps, N is number of particles and 3 is referring to x, y, z coordinates.

Also I use [this link](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucfbasc/Theory/vaf.html) to implement this autocorrelation array calculations functions.

So I ask you: what is wrong with this code? I can't find the issue.